# I'm having problems with the connotations of my sentence!

Tags: meaning-in-context, tense

The phrase: Wir gingen zum Reichstag, aber dann wurden wir verloren.

How clear would it be that the sentence should read 'We were going to the Reichstag but then we became lost.'?

Does it seem like I am saying that we WENT to the Reichstag and we are now lost? Thanks!

Comment: Who lost you? :)

Comment: Ja, *Zustandspassiv* –mit der Betonung auf dem Ergebnis– wäre vielleicht besser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to say that you wanted to go to the Reichstag but in the end couldn't get there then it would be better to say "Wir wollten zum Reichstag". This does a better job in expressing the intent where the result wasn't achieved.

For the second part: "dann gingen wir verloren" would be OK if you were part of a larger group of people where the others lost you while going somewhere or you just could not keep up with them.
If for instance you are travelling with your family and just cannot find your way then it would be best to say "dann haben wir uns verirrt" or "dann haben wir uns verlaufen", meaning that you lost or couldn't find the way

Answer (score 1):

We went to the Reichstag == Wir gingen zum Reichstag
This is correct.
But you can't say 'aber dann wurden wir verloren'..this could only say a speaking object (things that are owned by someone) ... it has to be 'aber dann gingen wir verloren' in the meaning of we got lost in the city.. even better would be 'aber dann haben wir uns verloren'.. more like loosing each other